# Sci Fi action movie where an elite group of people control business through a game they play online

Tags: story-identification, movie

I saw a movie where people are running from a group of powerful killers or a naughty company/organization. 
A woman was hired to find the entity/company.
A very overweight Asian man talks to them on line at one point.
(When I say overweight, I mean 400 pounds plus)

He talks to a virtual dolphin and tells it he is sorry but he cannot play with the dolphin that day. Eventually, the people find the fat guy in real life. He is sitting on a Chinese style boat in a river (I think it was a river).
(He is sitting in the rear of the boat. The boat is rather small. He is wearing a loin wrap like a sumo wrestler. In fact, I should most likely call him a sumo wrestler to describe the look.)

He had implants and wires coming out of his head like the Borg Queen did.

There is another part in the movie, where he replies to someones concern, saying, "I live a life of wonder..." (or something similar).

By the time the movie is over, the evil force has caused his death.
A team of Yakuza style (might actually be the Yakuza) commandos tear through everything trying to stop the truth from being discovered.
The huge Asian man ends up leaving little messages, like parts of himself, to guide the woman to the truth.
The ending reveals the naughty company/organization is a group of elite power brokers that control business by playing a game. Corporations lose or gain ground over nothing more than the turn of a game. (Including totally going out of business or making a fortune from nothing.)

Do you have any idea what movie this was?

Comment: Could this be it? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JzsOZuMXYgU

Comment: @Valorum Are you sure that's what you wanted to link to? It's a documentary. Admittedly presented by Michio Kaku, but still.

Comment: @MrLister - Interspersed in the documentary is a fiction story. Virtual reality dolphins abound and there's a fat guy wearing a body-suit thing. Not a great match, hence why I posted it as a comment.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but It is not the Future City documentary. 
Whatever this ends up being, I imagine it is rather obscure, since I have been searching for the movie for more than 5 years now on line in several forums and sites.
I wish there was a special effect listing. Someone out there is proud of the work they did to make these scenes possible.

Comment: Did you find this movie? I remember it. The guy hacks a group on the net that plays a chess type game that controls all the world's business. There is a woman, the muscle, who is hired to find out about this organization. She asks the obese man to find out what he can and he finds himself in their part of the web, then they kill him. He leaves virtual interactions of himself after he is dead to guide her to what he has found as well as how to defeat them, maybe(?) Please let me know, thanks!

Comment: YES YES YES!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
What you say makes me remember more of it now!!!
That is the one! 
I sure wish you had the title name.
Thanks for the added data.

Comment: Sam, I read your helpful post at around 4AM and it got me so wound up, I cannot go back to sleep now.
I have looked for this movie for years and years.
I just spent all this time searching with the new data you mentioned.
Sadly, I still cannot find it. 
You have it for sure!
I remember the hero of the story being upset that all the people died for a game...and the irony that all the failures and gains were not by planning, but chance in a game played by the very exclusive club.

Comment: Can you remember any of the actors? Or when it might have come out?

Comment: Related - Possible dupe; http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/152364/female-detective-fights-corrupt-group-that-kills-for-a-game

Comment: I wish I could remember an actor or when it came out. I do not.
The effects were pretty decent though, so it was not earlier than 95 or so.
I can remember the woman hired to find the baddies/game did not want to involve the "sumo" guy.
(I am shocked people into sci-fi did not get this, since the "sumo" guy is SOOO distinct. The "borg queen" implants in his head were extreme, as was his body and the boats location.)
This movie may well be a foreign film that had an English version.
I do not remember it being an overdub though. (The lips matched the sound if I remember right.)

Comment: I can't remember the name of the movie, but i know what you're talking about & the she found the bald guy on a small house boat & he left behind a virtual version of himself (still thin as she always saw him) that kept helping her.

Comment: That is the one for certain!
I would try to find it on Amazon if only I had the name...
There were no well-known actors I can search by, either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Avatar - Cyber wars  (or just Cyber wars)

[image]

From [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0270841/plotsummary?ref_=tt_ov_pl):

> Dash brings Victor to meet Julius and he shows Megacorp transactions in Sintawan to them. He explains that these **five companies make up the total infrastructure and have total control over Cyberlink. They form a powerful consortium and play a game based on the ancient Chinese game Wei Chi.** Sintawan is the playing field where they wage corporate war in accordance with the strategies of the five companies, manipulating the course of the society and everyone living here. Therefore the place is an illusion and nothing is what it seems and there is no distinction between the game and reality. Then Dash finds that they are all avatars. What will they do?

A [review](https://www.imdb.com/review/rw2204258/) mentions the dolphin:

> A decent movie with a good cyberpunk theme. A very Gibsonesque world complete with wetwiring, neural links, the matrix and even a holo-dolphin being used as an semi-sentient afterlife avatar.

Comment: Can you provide any more details in the answer that suggest similarity? Possible some plot points or a plot summary?

Comment: Well I'll be darned. Based on the IMDB summary I think you've cracked this one. I'd love to know how you tracked this down if you don't mind sharing.

Comment: I LOVE YOU!
Even if you are a big biker...I would give you a hug right now, I have been looking for this movie for...well, look at the date. It was LONG before I put it here!
THANK YOU SO MUCH!
Sure would like to know how you found it!
Thank you people to all who participated.
I feel like a little kid who just opened his dream toy at holiday time :)

Answer (score 6):

Could it perhaps be [Johnny Mnemonic (1995)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnny_Mnemonic_(film))?
It includes an evil mega corporation and the Yakuza. Also there's a Dolphin Hacker named Jones:

[image]

I can't find any references to a man on a boat, although there certainly seem to plenty of people in the movie with weird things on their heads:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it isn't Johnny Mnemonic.