# Female detective fights corrupt group that kills for a game

Tags: story-identification, movie, detective

A female detective works a case where an all powerful group meets on the "net" to control the world's business (yeah, it's that old, circa mid 90s to mid 00s). She can immerse herself completely in the cyber experience, interacting with characters in a 360 degree landscape, able to talk, walk and travel in the "net". She is seen next to a vehicle and interacting with a video conversation on the street.

She talks to a hacker who eventually helps her. His avatar is a well built, Asian monk with a half robe, and he is gentle and supportive with her in an amused manner. In real life he is a Japanese "Jabba the Hutt" looking bulbous character with cables directly connecting him to the "net". He is on an Asian looking boat docked in a port. He finds the group by accident and then is killed by them, the movie shows the dead body on the boat. The hacker leaves virtual video clips that the heroine can interact with and he helps her find the way to disable the group.

The scenes in the "net" are placid, peaceful and serene where the two travel, but are industrial and stark when the group meets to play the game.

There is a virtual dolphin that the hacker interacts with, swimming on a screen playfully. The dolphin is virtual, not a puppet like in *Johnny Mnemonic*.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JzsOZuMXYgU

Comment: @Valorum Seems likely...

Comment: I think the two are very similar, but the lead character is a female detective, not a male. Also I am pretty sure there was a third character, but I don't know for certain. I am not sure what the documentary link is about, could you explain Valorum?

Comment: Sam, I replied to you on my own post.
We seek the exact same movie.
Would you like to edit mine further?
I am not sure if having two of the same is prudent.
The extra character you seek is the man who hires the woman to find out what is going on.
I can see the last scene, with the red lights and the limos, when he finds out all commerce is controlled (actually pretty much every major event on the planet) through the elite game they play.

Comment: By the way, if I had been allowed to make a comment I would have.
The point of having two posts looking for the same movie kind of puzzles me...but the site is not mine...

Comment: It is the same movie, without question.

Comment: Working with this site has it challenges, but hey, you and I found it. Now all we need is the person with the title :-). I tried to delete this post, or comment on your post, no joy. This site has it's challenges... @JerryStratton

Comment: You need 4 more points I guess.
Trying to understand all the "levels" here.
(Kind of like a video game I suppose.)

Comment: I am too old for video games @JerryStratton

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sci Fi action movie where an elite group of people control business through a game they play online](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/137390) - see conversation between OPs, they were sure they were looking for the same thing. "Cyber Wars" answer occured one year after this exchange though

Comment: Cyber Wars it is! Thanks to the deep dive, ApproachingDarknessFish for the win! I can't comment on the other post, so I will thank you here.